# Xamarin, Azure, customauth and passing parameters

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-authentication

I am in the process of rewritting our app using Xamarin.Forms with a C# backend and I'm trying to use customauth on login. I've got it working to a point but am struggling to pass back to the Xamarin app everything I want from the backend. I'm getting the token and user id but want a bit more.

The backend code on succesfull login seems relatively straightforward:

```
return Ok(GetLoginResult(body));
```

where GetLoginResult() is:

```
private object GetLoginResult(IUser body)
        {
            var claims = new Claim[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, body.username)
            };

            JwtSecurityToken token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(
                claims, signingKey, audience, issuer, TimeSpan.FromDays(30));

            accounts account = db.accounts.Single(u => u.username.Equals(body.username));

            return new LoginResult(account)
            {
                authenticationToken = token.RawData,
            };
        }
```

and the LoginResult class is

```
public class LoginResult
{

    public LoginResult(accounts account)
    {
        Response = 200;
        CustomerId = account.CustomerId;
        Modules = account.Modules;
        User = new LoginResultUser
        {
            userId = account.id,
            UserName = account.UserName,
            EmployeeId = account.EmployeeId
        };
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Response")]
    public int Response { get; set; }
```

etc

In the app, I'm calling the customauth as follows:

```
MobileServiceUser azureUser = await _client.LoginAsync("custom", JObject.FromObject(account));
```

The result has the token and the correct userid but how can I fill the result with the additional properties passed back by the backend? I've got the backend working and tested using postman and the results I get there are what I want but I've been unable to find out how to get it deserialized in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I known, for custom auth , `MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync` would invoke `https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/custom`. When using [ILSPy](http://ilspy.net/) you could find that this method would only retrieve the `user.userId` and `authenticationToken` from the response to construct the `CurrentUser` of your `MobileServiceClient`. Per my understanding, you could leverage `MobileServiceClient.InvokeApiAsync` to retrieve the additional user info after the user has logged in successfully. Additionally, you could try to follow this [toturial](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/) for other possible approaches.

**UPDATE**

You could use `InvokeApiAsync` instead of `LoginAsync` to invoke the custom login endpoint directly, then retrieve the response and get the additional parameters as follows:

When logged successfully, I added a new property `userName` and response the client as follows:

[image]

For the client, I added a custom extension method for logging and retrieve the additional parameters as follows:

[image]

Here are the code snippet, you could refer to them:

**MobileServiceLoginExtend.cs**

```
public static class MobileServiceLoginExtend
{
    public static async Task CustomLoginAsync(this MobileServiceClient client, LoginAccount account)
    {
        var jsonResponse = await client.InvokeApiAsync("/.auth/login/custom", JObject.FromObject(account), HttpMethod.Post, null);
        //after successfully logined, construct the MobileServiceUser object with MobileServiceAuthenticationToken
        client.CurrentUser = new MobileServiceUser(jsonResponse["user"]["userId"].ToString());
        client.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken = jsonResponse.Value<string>("authenticationToken");

        //retrieve custom response parameters
        string customUserName = jsonResponse["user"]["userName"].ToString();
    }
}
```

**Login processing**

```
MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient("https://bruce-chen-002-staging.azurewebsites.net/");
var loginAccount = new LoginAccount()
{
    username = "brucechen",
    password = "123456"
};
await client.CustomLoginAsync(loginAccount);
```

Comment: Hi Bruce. Thanks for you reply. The article you linked to is the one I followed. I think what you are saying is that loginAsync cannot be used to pass back anyhting other then the userid and token?

Comment: Yes, I have decompiled the library and tracked the `MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync` method.

Comment: I found a workaround for your scenario, you could refer to my updates.

Comment: Thanks Bruce! I'll give that a try and report back

Comment: Worked a treat. Thanks Bruce!